# iTunes connect difference between "updates" and "sales"

Tags: app-store-connect

Yesterday, my app got 74 downloads in sales but 134 in updates.  Are these numbers combined? I'm very confused.  How I just look at the downloads overall?

Answer (score 0):

Sales are unique downloads of your app. Updates are users who are either updating from a previous version of your app or re-downloading it after they had purchased but deleted it.

Comment: Someone might have bought the app once and then downloaded it onto all 3 of their Macs. That would yield 1 sale but 3 updates. That's just one example.

Comment: So if you had 100 updates, that would just be "100 downloads of that update in a day?"

Comment: Yes, that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

As @SevenBits says, they are completely different numbers and the overall downloads depends on how you define it.

IF:
1. Overall downloads = New sales (whether free or paid) + updates, then you have to add 74 + 134 = 208.
2. Overall downloads = Only New sales free or paid (because updates doesn't count), then its 74.

There isn't a place to look at the sum of updates and new sales/downloads.

Lastly, this is not a programming related question... please see the [SO guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for types of questions to post.

Comment: Is there really a place to look for OVERALL downloads, so sales + upgrades?